# Operaciones aritméticas en el view con Django o Javascript

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-forms

Buen día, quisiera saber algo, necesito actualizar un valor total, de un campo consultado por el user a la hora de logearse en la aplicación, mediante una petición POST, ya sea suma, division, etc. Por medio de un formulario, dependiendo de lo que vaya hacer el usuario. Puesto que el dato ingresado por el usuario, seria en el front, estoy algo confundido. Ahora quisiera saber, si se hace mediante javascript o en Django se puede hacer y como seria, he llevado a cabo algunos experimentos, pero ninguno funciona hasta el momento, me puede ayudar por favor.

```
views.py

@login_required
def adicion(request):
"""Gestion de solicitudes"""
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = addiForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
    return redirect('send')
else:
    form = addiForm(instance=request.user)
    args = {'form':form}
return render(request, 'plantillas/adicionar.html', args)


models.py 

class LocalUsers(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
d_pendientes = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
h_pendientes = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)

class Peticion(model.Models):
solit_choices = (
    ('Adicionar','Adicionar'),
)
solicitudes_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
usuario = models.ForeignKey(LocalUsers, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
null=True, blank=True)
dias_adicion = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=False)
horas_adicion = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=False)

@property
def suma_valores_fk(self):
    return (self.d_pendientes + self.usuario.dias_adicion)

def save(self):
    self.total = self.suma_valores
    super (LocalUsers, self).save()
```

Answer (score 0):

Para hacer operaciones entre campos puedes usar el method @property te pongo dos ejemplos:

Encadenar texto:

```
  from django.db import models

  class Persona(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    apellido_paterno = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    apellido_materno = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    nombre_completo = models.CharField(max_length=150)

    @property
    def fullname(self):
        return ''.join([self.apellido_paterno,' ', self.apellido_materno, ' ', self.nombre])

    def save(self):
    self.nombre_completo = self.fullname
    super (Persona, self).save()
```

En este primer ejemplo tenemos 4 campos 1 nombre 2 apellido parteno y 3 apellido materno hacemos un join con el method @property y el resultado lo guardamos reescribiendo el metodo save.

```
from django.db import models

class Calculo(models.Model):
    valor1 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    valor2 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)


    @property
    def suma_valores(self):
        return (self.valor1 + self.valor2)


    def save(self):
    self.total = self.suma_valores
    super (Calculo, self).save()
```

En este ejemplo tenemos campos numericos en el ejmplo en particular son DecimalField, la funcion suma valores nos indica que hay una operacion de suma(+) entre los campos valor1 y valor 2 en la sobreescritura del metodo save guardamos la funcion suma_valores en el campo total

Nota: asi como aqui pusimos sumar, se puede ocupar (-) menos. (*) multiplicacion, (/) division, no estoy seguro si acepta  operadores logicos (<,>,=), podrias investigar un poco mas.

3er Caso calculando datos de distintos modelos:

```
from django.db import models

class Calculo(models.Model):
    persona = models.ForeignKey(Persona, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    valor1 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    valor2 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)

class Persona(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    apellido_paterno = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    apellido_materno = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    nombre_completo = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    valor3 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
```

En este tercer caso respondiendo a tu pregunta tenemos un campo ForeignKey que relaciona al modelo Calculo con Persona.

Aqui ocupamos de igual manera

```
@property
def suma_valores_fk(self):
    return (self.valor1 + self.valor2 + self.persona.valor3)

def save(self):
    self.total = self.suma_valores
    super (Calculo, self).save()
```

En este caso para agregar al valor del campo relación a través de la ForeignKey, ponemos persona (Es el nombre del campo dentro de nuestro modelo Calculo) seguido del campo al que queremos acceder.

Espero esto responda tu pregunta.

Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder, pero de la forma que me estas mostrando, se puede agregar campos de distintos modelos? Porque un valor estaria en el modelo del user logged y el otro estaria en el modelo de la peticion que haria l usuario.

Comment: Se puede mientras tengas la relación "one to many" o "many to many", actualizo la respuesta y lo comento.

Comment: Gracias, mira edite mi pregunta siguiendo la secuencia, de lo que me mostrastes en tus respuestas. Ahora, no hace efecto, hay que tocar algo en el views.py o en el forms.py, gracias brother. <3

Comment: def get_sum(self):
    return (self.dias_adicion + self.usuario.d_pendientes)   te falto poner .usuario para que atraves de la FK acceder a los valores del modelo LocalUser

Comment: Ok, creo que estoy muy cerca bro hehehe, agruegue lo que dices. Ahora el error que manda en el vscode Instance of 'CharField' has no 'dias_adicion' memberpylint(no-member), eso es? Oye muchisimas gracias, me esfuerzo hehe