# Multiplicación de propiedades en un modelo de Django

Tags: django, django-models

Tengo una pregunta quizás muy básica pero no he dado con la solución.

¿como puedo hacer las operaciones aritméticas en un modelo de Django (en este caso mutiplicar) para pasar el resultado a otro campo?

He intentado esto sin resultados. [Operaciones aritméticas en el view con Django o Javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/268736)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51936217

Mi modelo:

```
class Calculo(models.Model):
   cantidad = models.IntegerField(default=0)
   valor_unitario = models.IntegerField(default=0)
   valor = models.IntegerField(default=calculo_valor)

class Meta:
    ordering = ('-fecha',)

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.cantidad)

def calculo_valor(self):
    return int(self.cantidad * self.valor_unitario)
```

En mi template quiero mostrar el resultado en una tabla

```
<th> {{ object.calculo_valor}} </th>
```

Espero me puedan ayudar, gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas poniendo el int en variables que ya son numericas.

```
def get_calculo_valor(self):
    return self.cantidad * self.valor_unitario


template:

{% for item in object.Calculo.all %}

   <th> {{ item.get_calculo_valor}} </th>

{% endfor %}
```

Avísame como te va.

Saludos.

Comment: No me funciona, pasa lo mismo, no muestra ningún valor. y tampoco guarda en el campo valor.

Comment: podras pasarme mas info para ver tu codigo como esta hecho... yo lo tengo asi en mi proyecto E-commerce y me funciona bien.. yo tengo django 2.2.9 y python 3.8....

Comment: Gracias por responder. En realidad el código es distinto pero estoy haciendo esta prueba básica para hacer la operación simple de multiplicar dos campos y no me funciona (debería funcionando)

En minutos editar mi pregunta agregando el código.

Comment: Ahora me funcionó la forma que me indicas, gracias. Solo que no se como guardar el resultado en el campo valor. ¿me podrías ayudar con eso?

Comment: Hola.. perdon por la tardanza de respuesta... pudiste solucionar sobre el guardar valor?

Comment: si, encontré una forma no se si será la mejor forma.
    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.valor = self.calculo_valor()
        super(Calculo, self).save(*args,**kwargs)

Comment: por lo que indicas tu tienes un proyecto parecido a lo que estoy haciendo. Este calculo me genera una columna con los resultados por cada item o producto. necesito sumar todos estos valores para hacer total y al hacer: 
subtotal = Model.objects.aggregate(Sum('valor'))['valor__sum'] or 0.00
me suma la totalidad de la columna en la BD. no solo los del documento.
hice la consulta acá: 
https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/337270
Me haría INMENSAMENTE feliz si puede echarme una mano.

Answer (score 1):

vine buscando la misma respuesta y me funciono así
estoy aprendiendo a usar django asi que puede que encuentren cosas que talvez no se hacen asi o no sea la mejor manera

mi modelo

```
class Product(models.Model):
  nombre=models.CharField(max_length=50)
  cantidad=models.FloatField()
  precio=models.FloatField()
  categoria=models.ForeignKey(Categories, on_delete=models.CASCADE , null=False)
  
  class Meta:
   verbose_name='producto'
   verbose_name_plural='productos' 
   
  
  def __str__(self):
      return "Nombre: %s     Categoría: %s    Precio: %s  Cantidad: %s" %(self.nombre,self.categoria, self.precio, self.cantidad)
    
  def total(self):
    return (self.cantidad * self.precio)
```

el views.py

```
def checkInventory(request):
  
  if request.user.is_authenticated:
       
        products = Product.objects.all()
           
        context ={"products": products,}
        
        return render(request, 'checkinventory/checkinventory.html',context)

  else:
      
      return redirect('/signin')
```

y en el template quedo asi (|redondeo es un templatetags que hice para quitar los ceros al final )

```
{% for product in products %}
  <tr>
    <td data-label="id" >{{ product.id }}</td>
    <td data-label="nombre" >{{ product.nombre }}</td>
    <td data-label="categoría" >{{ product.categoria }}</td>
    <td data-label="cantidad" name="cantidad" >{{ product.cantidad|redondeo }}</td>
    <td data-label="valor Ud." >{{ product.precio|redondeo}}</td>
    <td data-label="valor Uds." >{{ product.total|redondeo}}</td>
    <td class="acciones" data-label="acciones" ><button class="btn__edit">Editar</button><button class="btn__delete" >Eliminar</button></td>
   <tr>
     
  {% endfor %}
```